# OpenCL C++ wrapper. Is it possible to extract the platform and device from a Context class?

Tags: c++, opencl

I am learning OpenCL and I already know this problem can be solved by first setting up platform & device the proper way.

What I would like to find out is.
In the free and online course https://handsonopencl.github.io/ they start setting up the environment in a more shorthand way that I like.

I am now at Exercise9 and am supposed to write a kernel and host program from scratch. I want to solve it in this short handed way that skips setting up platform and device and instead goes straight to calling the Context class.
Like this.

```
    #define DEVICE CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU
    try {
    // Create a context
    cl::Context context(DEVICE);

    // Load source and build
    cl::Program program(context, kernelSource, true);

    // Get command queue
    cl::CommandQueue queue(context);

    // Create kernel functor
    auto pi = cl::make_kernel<int>(program, "pi");


}
catch (cl::Error err) {
    std::cout << "Exception" << std::endl;
    std::cerr << "ERROR: " << err.what() << "(" << err_code(err.err()) << ")" << std::endl;

}
```

Now. I have everything setup properly. The C++ code compiles and if I provide a correct kernelSource then the program will also compile.

So far so good.

The problem arrives when I made a mistake in my kernel source and would like to get the CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG. The only calls that I find requires that I pass a cl::device (which obviously should've existed at some point inside the Context constructor). But since I took the shorthand route I do not have this at hand outside the constructor.

I know I can perform the calls that I skipped out on and get the values I need. But I feel that takes away from the benefit of writing this in the short hand way.

**Is there any way to get a hold of the device and platform identifiers from inside the Context class ?**
My C++ is not the strongest but from looking at the class I could not find a way.

**Is there any other way in this wrapper or call that I have missed out on that can retrieve the build log for me without first setting up device and platform ?**

**Is there any really strong reasons why I shouldn't set my code up this way ?**

The only benefits I can see of scanning through platform and device is if I was interested in getting capabilities and making an informed choice. In this case I am not since I know which device I want to use already.

EDIT:
Adding this code snippet to show how I solved my problem using the context.getInfo() provided in the answer.

```
    cl::Context context;
cl::Program program;
cl::CommandQueue queue;

try {
    // Create a context
    context = cl::Context(DEVICE);

    // Load source and build
    //program = cl::Program(context, kernelSource, true); // Don't do this. It will error with "abort() has been called
    program = cl::Program(context, kernelSource);
    program.build();

    // Bind variables
    d_sum = cl::Buffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, sizeof(float) * 1);

    // Get command queue
    queue = cl::CommandQueue(context);

    // Create kernel functor
    auto clpi = cl::make_kernel<int, cl::Buffer, cl::LocalSpaceArg>(program, "pi");

    // Run kernel
    clpi(cl::EnqueueArgs(queue, cl::NDRange(num_steps), cl::NDRange(workgroup_size)), num_steps, d_sum, d_local_sums);

    // Extract sum
    cl::copy(queue, d_sum, h_sum.begin(), h_sum.end());

}
catch (cl::Error err) {
    std::cout << "Exception" << std::endl;
    std::cerr << "ERROR: " << err.what() << "(" << err_code(err.err()) << ")" << std::endl;

    if (err.err() == CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE)
    {
        for (cl::Device dev : context.getInfo<CL_CONTEXT_DEVICES>())
        {
            // Check the build status
            cl_build_status status = program.getBuildInfo<CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_STATUS>(dev);
            if (status != CL_BUILD_ERROR)
                continue;
            // Get the build log
            std::string name = dev.getInfo<CL_DEVICE_NAME>();
            std::string buildlog = program.getBuildInfo<CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG>(dev);
            std::cerr << "Build log for " << name << ":" << std::endl
                << buildlog << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a list of devices associated with a context by using `clGetContextInfo(CL_CONTEXT_DEVICES)` function (or `Context::getInfo()` for C++) . Then you can iterate over these devices and ask for a program build status or a build log for each device.

Same function can be used to get a platform from a context: for `CL_CONTEXT_PROPERTIES` query will return an array of properties, which should contain a value for `CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM`.

Comment: I have managed to solve this in a, I think, nice and pretty enough way. I will edit my post to reflect how the code looks right at this moment.

Comment: I had some more questions in the text but you answered the one in the subject so I'll accept this as answer.